# Email router crm 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, email-router

While configuring the Email router for crm 2015. when fetching the User and queues details. getting this error

### Email Router Configuration Manager

The Email Router Configuration Manager was unable to retrieve user and queue information from the Microsoft Dynamics CRM server. This may indicate that the Microsoft Dynamics CRM server is busy. Verify that URL '' is correct. Additionally, this problem can occur if specified access credentials are insufficient. To try again, click Load Data. (The decryption key could not be obtained because HTTPS protocol is enforced, but not enabled. Enable HTTPS protocol, and try again.)

Answer (score 1):

From: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699774.aspx

1) Make sure the user account that is running the Email Router service is a member of the Active Directory directory service PrivUserGroup security group.

2) Make sure the account that is specified in the Access Credentials field on the General tab of the Email Router Configuration Profile dialog box is a Microsoft Dynamics CRM administrative user. If the access credentials are set to Local System Account, the computer account must be a member of the Active Directory PrivUserGroup security group.

3) Make sure that the URL of the Microsoft Dynamics CRM deployment is spelled correctly. The OrganizationUniqueName part of the URL must be spelled exactly as it appears in the Microsoft Dynamics CRM server. To determine the OrganizationUniqueName, start the Microsoft Dynamics CRM web application as a user who has the System Customizer role. Click Settings, and then click Customizations. On the Customization page, click Developer Resources. The OrganizationUniqueName is displayed below the Organization Unique Name label. For more information, see Configure the Email Router.